# Generate list of values, based on multiple matching columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Python to identify different **ROUTES** based on **Origin State** and **Dest State**.

I then took all the **ROUTES** and found the corresponding **Carrier Name**s for those **ROUTES**. This was done manually (see below) but I want to create a for loop and make a table for every unique route that would be filled with **Carrier Name**s and would then be transferred into an excel file.

These are the coulmns available:

```
Carrier Name               
Origin City, State          
Destination City, State   
Delivered Date            
Order ID                   
Load ID                    
Units                     
Customer                 
Price                     
Rev/Mile                   
Average Margin%            
Origin State                
Dest State
```

*I have identified unique routes by using this function:*

```
ROUTES = df.groupby(['Origin State', 'Dest State']).size()
df.groupby(['Origin State', 'Dest State']).size()
```

*And then I came up with this function to find the corresponding carriers for the route MI -> IN , 7 **Carrier Names** appeared*

```
new_df = df[((df['Origin State'] == "MI") & (df['Dest State'] == "IN"))]
new_df
```

[result from the above function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOIjn.png)

What I would like to do now is to automate the above function so that it runs over all of the unique matches of **Origin State** and **Dest State** i.e. unique **ROUTES** and finds the corresponding **Carrier Name**s by placing them into individual tables that correspond to each route

Comment: `df_dict = {k:g for k,g in df.groupby(['Origin State', 'Dest State'])}` need this?

Comment: Thanks! This worked but its in a dictionary format and I am having trouble placing the unique findings into separate data frames so that I can them put them into an csv file.